# Why Veritaserum wasn't used to detect all true death eaters?

Tags: harry-potter

It's kind of strange, that there were a bunch of Death Eaters who were able to escape punishment. Some of them claimed to be under the *Imperius Curse*.

However, it's kind of easy to check just by giving them the Veritaserum and asking whether they were truly under the curse or not.

Maybe unrelated thought. It looks like Death Eaters perform Unforgivable Curses left and right. As I understand, that's the whole point of word "Unforgivable," that if they truly did that, then it should be very hard to say "I am sorry, I didn't mean to".

It's just strange that a bunch of them were still around at Voldemort's rebirth.

Comment: I expect it wasn't that they escaped punishment because they didn't get dosed with veritaserum, but that they didn't get dosed because they had *already* manipulated those higher up authorities into letting them escape pnishment... in exchange for gold, influence, and maybe the (absolutely false) perception that they weren't going to cause real trouble without their leader, or something.  Cause and effect are kinda reversed.

Comment: @Megha Yeah. This is an interesting idea (supported by Lucius Malfoy story).

Comment: actually, it's not a duplicate of that question. But the answer to that question answers this question as well. Does that count for this question to be a duplicate?

Comment: Actually, I believe Veritaserum - objective/subjective doesn't answer it. Yeah. Veritaserum is subjective. However, it doesn't mean that it provides 0 useful information. As example you can ask whether the person had the feeling like described : "Harry felt a floating sensation as every thought and worry in his head was wiped gently away, leaving nothing but a vague, untraceable happiness". Sure. The answer will be subjective, but it will provide information whether a person was under Imperius curse or not.